# using non-modular libraries with SystemJs and jspm

Tags: systemjs, jspm

To include ngDraggable into a project using systemJs and jspm, we need to add an override in package.json as below:

```
 "overrides": {
      "github:fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable@0.1.8": {
        "dependencies": {
          "angular": "jspm:angular@1.5.3"
        },
        "shim": {
          "ngDraggable": [
            "angular"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

It's twice that we are mentioning that ngDraggable has a dependency on angular.. moreover the config.js file created by jspm also mentions this

```
 "github:fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable@0.1.8": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.5.3"
    },
```

Why do systemJs and jspm need this mentioned in so many different places ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not twice since **dependencies** and **shim.deps** do different stuff.

The [shim deps](https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm#shim-configuration) actually modifies the ngDraggable file and adds a "deps angular" statement. This allows you to specify each file dependency separately.